# Permalink prefix change

Tags: permalinks

Is it possible to change permalink prefix of posts i.e. on switching the langugae

```
/blog/%post%
```

to

```
 /aktuelle/%post%
```

Comment: Does `/blog` not refer to a physical directory?

Comment: no, just a prefix which we can add in permalink -> custom.  at the moment structure is like this /blog/%postname%/  but at the moment when i switch the long though post url itself gets updated but prefix remains the same.